# MYSQL Query not working, is there a simpler query for this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `STUDENT` table which contains data about students from a faculty:

```
STUDENT(ID, Name, Grade, ID_Tutor)
```

**Structure** and **data**:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
    (`ID` int, `Name` varchar(5), `Grade` int, `ID_Tutor` int);

INSERT INTO STUDENT
    (`ID`, `Name`, `Grade`, `ID_Tutor`)
VALUES
    (1,    'A',     10,       NULL),
    (2,    'B',     9.5,      1),
    (3,    'C',     9,        1),
    (4,    'D',     8,        1),
    (5,    'E',     7,        4),
    (6,    'F',     8,        1),
    (7,    'G',     5,        7),
    (10,   'H',     6,        5)
    (11,   'I',     7,        3),
    (12,   'J',     9,        10),
    (13,   'K',     9.6,      11),
    (14,   'L',     8.9,      5),
    (15,   'M',     9.9,      13),
    (16,   'N',     7,        2),
    (17,   'O',     7.9,      2),
    (18,   'P',     2,        15);
```

**Top 5** faculty grades:

```
    `ID`, `Name`, `Grade`, `ID_Tutor`
    (1,    'A',     10,       NULL),
    (15,   'M',     9.9,      13),
    (13,   'K',     9.6,      11),
    (2,    'B',     9.5,      1),
    (3,    'C',     9,        1),
    (12,   'J',     9,        10),
```

In **result** should appear students with these tutors from the above table.

I want to make a SQL query (**MYSQL**) to find

- **student name**,
- **tutor name** and
- **tutor grade**

for students whose tutor has a **grade** in **top 5** faculty students (and without using `LIMIT` and/or `ROWNUM` - for a Oracle solution).

**Result** should look like this:

```
| student name | tutor name | tutor grade |
       'B'           'A'          10           
       'C'           'A'          10           
       'D'           'A'          10           
       'F'           'A'          10           
       'P'           'M'           9.9           
       'M'           'K'           9.6              
       'N'           'B'           9.5            
       'O'           'B'           9.5            
       'I'           'C'           9
```

I tried something like this (but **not** working) and I think I'm complicating a lot... (and I should not use `ROWNUM`)

```
SELECT 
    s.ID, 
    s.Name Student, 
    s.Grade, 
    p.ID_Tutor, 
    p.Grade
FROM 
    STUDENT s,
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT 
                t.Name Tutor , 
                t.ID , 
                Grade Grade_Tutor 
            FROM STUDENT s
                JOIN STUDENT t 
                    on s.ID_Tutor = t.ID
            GROUP BY t.Name, t.ID)
        ORDER BY 3 desc ) 
    WHERE ROWNUM < 6) p
WHERE s.ID_Tutor = p.ID
```

Give me this **error**:

```
    #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I get your question right, that a simple `SELECT * FROM STUDENT ORDER BY Grade DESC LIMIT 5` would solve the problem?

Comment: No, that query is just for returning the Top5.     I want to make a SQL query (MYSQL) to find student name, tutor name and tutor grade for students whose tutor has a grade in top 5 faculty students (and without using LIMIT and/or ROWNUM).

Comment: Neither limit nor RowNum (even though myswl doesn't have the latter). So is a cursor okay? Oh and presumably this is the top five distinct grades, ie in your example, if Student Q have got a 9.6 from tutor 5, Students Q, H and L would be in the output.

Comment: If there is a (homework) requirement to not use `LIMIT`, please add the `[homework]` tag. You would need a self-join to achieve that.

Comment: @ypercube It's not a homework. The question it's an example of a subject from an Computer Science examination, where the exactly request was not to use LIMIT (or ROWNUM for a Oracle solution).

Comment: I think most people here include "self-learning" in the [homework] tag. Think of it as homework where the teacher is yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to **@TehShrike**, is his answer!!!

The only "downside" is that is using LIMIT, but if someone has a version without LIMIT please post it; until then, thanks again, **@TehShrike**!

```
SELECT 
        student.NAME AS student_name, 
        top_five_tutors.NAME AS tutor_name, 
        top_five_tutors.grade AS tutor_grade
FROM (
        SELECT 
                tutor.id, 
                tutor.NAME, 
                tutor.Grade
        FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                                id_tutor AS id
                FROM student
             ) AS tutor_ids

        JOIN student AS tutor 
            ON tutor.id = tutor_ids.id

        ORDER BY tutor.grade DESC
            LIMIT 5
     ) AS top_five_tutors

JOIN student 
    ON student.id_tutor = top_five_tutors.id
```

Comment: There is no downside on using `LIMIT`. The query is fine.

Comment: @ypercube When I say "downside", I meant that this solution uses LIMIT although it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your are lacking of several table alias on your code. Check this working [SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cded5/8). But it does not return any value as I just added some dumb values. Feel free to use it and test your results.

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name Student, s.Grade, p.ID_Tutor, p.Grade_tutor
FROM STUDENT s,
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT t.Name Tutor, t.ID , s.Grade Grade_Tutor, s.ID_Tutor
               FROM STUDENT s
               JOIN STUDENT t
                    on s.ID_Tutor = t.ID
            GROUP BY t.Name, t.ID) innerTable
         ORDER BY 3 desc ) secondInnerTable
     WHERE @ROWNUM < 6) p
WHERE s.ID_Tutor = p.ID
```

Comment: As you said, it does not return any values.

Comment: Yes, it does not return values as I filled with dumb values not paying attention to them. But if you fill the table with some correct sample values or directly edit your question and add all structure and data then you can get a better answer.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that it does not return any values from my table filled with correct sample values. (i added them in latest edit)

Comment: Mysql doesnt have ROWNUM, you can emulate it with user variables.